# Protocol being switched during redirects

Tags: php, azure, cakephp, azure-web-app-service, cakephp-3.0

In my CakePHP 3.10 application, the redirects are changing the protocols and breaking the app. This is being deployed to an App Service (PHP 7.4) in Azure.

I'm not seeing this on another LAMP stack (RHEL, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.3, https configured) on premise.

Example, logging out of the application.

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->getRequest()->getSession()->write('isAdmin',false);
    $this->Flash->success(__('You are now logged out.'));
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

During inspection of the traffic (via Edge's > Inspect > Network), here's what I see (notice Response Header Location change from https to http):

General

```
Request URL: https://my.domain.com/users/logout
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: my.ip.here:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Response Headers

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 19 Dec 2021 13:08:05 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Location: http://my.domain.com/
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: CAKEPHP=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: CAKEPHP=c2be7c7d45c9418b06356bd95796ff8f; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.24
```

Request Headers

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: csrfToken=09206701259fb54445122132512cf0e8f00cf2ac2f2cf42a34a49cd221b9e797c36d919696daad8d2fc77a0373e417e5e59a89a0cacc9c408ebeede1fc0b4446; CAKEPHP=c6ebd1412956de948b4857c4a0791f04
DNT: 1
Host: my.domain.com
Referer: https://my.domain.com/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Microsoft Edge";v="96"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36 Edg/96.0.1054.62
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many load balancers, [**the Azure ones also like to terminate SSL**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux#detect-https-session), so that the requests that are reaching PHP will be unencrypted, making the `env('HTTPS')` lookup fail that CakePHP applications use by default to build the full base URL.

> ```php
> /*
>  * Set the full base URL.
>  * This URL is used as the base of all absolute links.
>  *
>  * If you define fullBaseUrl in your config file you can remove this.
>  */
> if (!Configure::read('App.fullBaseUrl')) {
>     $s = null;
>     if (env('HTTPS')) {
>         $s = 's';
>     }
>
>     $httpHost = env('HTTP_HOST');
>     if (isset($httpHost)) {
>         Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', 'http' . $s . '://' . $httpHost);
>     }
>     unset($httpHost, $s);
> }
> ```

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.10.1/config/bootstrap.php#L131-L148**

The linked Azure docs suggest checking the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header instead, which is being populated by the load balancer, but you need to take into account that depending on the environment that the application runs in, this header could also have been set by the client, so I wouldn't generally recommend using it.

I would instead suggest to hardcode the protocol, or better yet, set the complete full base URL manually (at least in the past `HTTP_HOST` has been a problem too, as some servers accepted custom values sent from the client), eg:

```php
Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', 'https://' . $httpHost);
```

or set `App.fullBaseUrl` in your `config/app.php` (or `config/app_local.php`).

Comment: I opted to set it in app_local.php. I confirmed on the server via SSH that it was there. It's still going to http, however. Strange.

Comment: @TechFanDan The file being there is one thing, the file actually being used another. You gotta do some more digging to figure whether the config is actually being set (correctly).

Comment: I'll check it out. So far, the other configs in there are being used (ie. db credentials, etc). Maybe I missed something as I simply appended it to the app_local.php file.

Comment: Figured it out! The setting in app_local.php was missing the prefix App. Seems to work now! thanks!

Comment: For completeness, the full line added in `app_local.php` was: `'App.fullBaseUrl' => 'https://my.domain.com'`

Comment: @TechFanDan I've updated my answer to make it more clear that the option is nested in `App`. Also added a note regarding `HTTP_POST` being a possible problem too.